# 'document is not defined' canvas/discord

Tags: node.js, canvas, discord, bots

I'm trying make a animated banner to discord server, but I have some problems with that. I don't know why document is not defined. I tried a bunch of ways, but none of them worked.

```js
try {
        let guild = await client.guilds.cache.get(guildId.id);

        const voiceChannels = guild.channels.cache.filter((c) => c.type === "GUILD_VOICE");
        let count = 0;
        for (const [, voiceChannel] of voiceChannels) count += voiceChannel.members.size;
        var canvas = createCanvas(420, 236);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.textAlign = "center"
        ctx.font = "20px Kanit Black"
        ctx.fillStyle = '000001'
        const encoder = new GIFEncoder(420, 236, {emptyColor: true, dynamicColors: true})
            encoder.setRepeat(0);
            encoder.setQuality(10)
        await gifFrames({ url: `${__dirname}/banner-beta.gif`, frames: 'all', outputType: 'canvas', cumulative: false}).then((frameData) => {
            for(let i = 0; i < frameData.length; i++) {
                encoder.setDelay(frameData[i].frameInfo.delay * 15);
                console.log(frameData[0])
                console.log(frameData[i])
                ctx.drawImage((frameData[i]).getImage(), 0, 0, 420, 236)
                ctx.fillText(`${count}`, 50, 90)
                console.log(ctx)
                encoder.addFrame(ctx);
            }
            encoder.finish();
            console.log(encoder.out.getData())
            var attachment = new MessageAttachment(encoder.out.getData(), 'banner.gif');
            guild.channels.cache.get("909860310171648050").send({ files: [attachment] }).catch(console.log);

        })
        //guild.setBanner(canvas.toBuffer()).catch(console.error);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
```

error:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at savePixels (C:\Users\hotab\Desktop\Root\node_modules\save-pixels-jpeg-js-upgrade\save-pixels.js:127:20)
    at Object.getImage (C:\Users\hotab\Desktop\Root\node_modules\gif-frames\gif-frames.js:105:20)
    at C:\Users\hotab\Desktop\Root\utils\banner.js:31:34
```

Comment: What is the code in `banner.js`, line 31 (where the stacktrace starts)? Is your code snippet running in NodeJS or in the browser?

Comment: ctx.drawImage((frameData[i]).getImage(), 0, 0, 420, 236)

running in node.js

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR:

Your code runs in NodeJS, in which there is no `document` object because it does not make sense on a backend server. So using `document` results in an exception.

#### More details

You are using the node module `gif-frames` that depends on another node module called `save-pixels-jpeg-js-upgrade` which tries to access the `document` object that only exists in a browser context (see code [here](https://github.com/scijs/save-pixels/blob/master/save-pixels.js#L127)).

Either the documentation of `gif-frames` stating that it can run in both Node and browsers contexts is incorrect or there are some restrictions to some APIs, which you are facing here. Based on the node module code, it seems to be limited to the CANVAS case, but I can't help you any further...